# Arithmetic Overflow

Tags: document-library, file, reports

I have to report weekly on the number of documents being stored in one of our document libraries. My manager wants the headline figures:

- Total number of files stored
- Average file size
- Total file size

Until today I have been able to provide these with a custom view. When I tried to run the report this morning I got an error with a correlation ID. I tracked this in the error log and found the following error:

> `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int.`

I've figured out that the total file size has gone over 2,147,483,647 bytes. Is there a way that I can recast the file size field as a `bigint` or is there a better way to report these figures?

Comment: The ``Int`` limitation is a SharePoint Application limitation, that code originates from (very) old SharePoint versions and was never adapted to handle larger values. It is not a database (field) restriction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided you have a ListView with **all** files displayed, **and** the File Size is displayed in the View,
you can execute client-side code from the Developer Console (or a CEWP, or CSR)

```
function countFileSize(min,max){//in bytes
    min=min|0;
    max=max||Math.pow(2,31);
    var total=0,count=0;
    ctx.ListData.Row.forEach(function(row){
        var size=parseInt(row.File_x0020_Size);//needs to be displayed in the View!
        //console.log('item ID',size,'item ID:',row.ID,row.FileLeafRef);
        if(size>min && size<max){
            count++;
            total+=size;
        } else {
            console.error('outside boundaries:',size,row.FileLeafRef);

        }
    });
    console.info('With byte boundaries:',min,max,' there are',count,'files','totalling',total,'bytes. Average:',~~(total/count),'bytes per file');
};
console.clear();
countFileSize();
```

Comment: This code works brilliantly on small lists but the list I am working with contains 20,000+ documents. Trying to display this many in a single view has locked up my IE multiple times in the last hour.

Comment: Yes, in order for this to work **all** items (or all you want to count) need to be displayed on one page. Anything over the (Microsoft recommened) [5000 listitems](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2759051) will not perform well.

Comment: You might be better of doing this (same concept) with PowerShell.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with PowerShell, I'll have a look at it. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Unless you add over 5000 documents a week, a weekly delta report can be created with a View filtered on **Created > [Today]-7**

Comment: SharePoint is a new technology for us, the number added has been increasing since September. Last week it hit 6000, I'm expecting it to plateau around 6500 every week.

Comment: [5000](https://www.google.nl/search?q=5000&tbs=qdr:y&tbo=1&as_oq=sharepoint&gws_rd=cr,ssl&ei=ipY8VrPtCcKePKfsh6gC) is the ever annoying number in SharePoint